# How to get dictionary length in VB Script?

Tags: dictionary, vbscript

Please help me. I am a little bit confuse about getting the length or size of dictionary in vbscript without creating manual function to itterate the dictionary. Is there any available methode to get the length of the dictionary? (example like UBound in array).

Thank you for your attention,
Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Count](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/vbscript/13992.asp). The Count property is used to determine the number of key/item pairs in the Dictionary object.

Comment: Correct. You can also use the ubound on the keys or items array: `Ubound(myDict.Keys)` / `Ubound(myDict.Items)`. Note: 0 indexed!